# Using firebase with WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, watchkit, watchos-2

I am attempting to use the firebase database in my watchKit app. I have developed this feature on my iPhone application but have found it difficult to do the same on my Watch app. When I attempted to import firebase into the VC class in watch app, it is creating an error `no such module 'firebase'`.

Is it possible to use firebase inside a watch app?

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/QZ3X9JLjDwk and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635082/new-firebase-with-watch-os2-3

Comment: I've created firebase feature request for that: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4556

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sadly there is no `Firebase` support for `watchOS2` and `watchOS3` due to the fact that there's no support for `CFNetwork` in these versions of `watchOS` and `Firebase` is highly dependent on this framework. [Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/QZ3X9JLjDwk) (thanks for the link @FrankvanPuffelen in comments).

You have two alternatives:

1. Use the `Firebase REST API` directly from your watch app.
2. Handle all `Firebase` communication from the `iPhone` app and use the `WatchConnectivity` framework to send the relevant changes to your watch app.

Depending on your exact use case, you could choose any of the two. The main advantages/disadvantages of these two are that the `WatchConnectivity` framework is quite limited as in when it can be used. Both of your apps needs to be running at least in the background for the `WatchConenctivity` framework to work. On the other hand, if you choose to use the `REST API`, you don't need the watch app to communicate with the `iPhone` counterpart, the watch app can directly get the `Firebase` data using network requests. However, in this scenario, the network usage will be bigger, since you will need to essentially fetch the same information both for the `iPhone` and watch apps.

**Update for watchOS 6**:
Firebase Messaging has been released with watchOS support, however, the Realtime Database along with other Firebase SDKs are still not supported. You can track the progress of them in [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/269) GitHub issue, which also contains links to the specific feature request issues for the other SDKs.

Comment: @tymac the watch doesn't need to have direct internet access to be able to make network calls from your WatchKit Extension. The phone tethers its cellular connection to the watch in case of cellular connection, otherwise the watch can directly connect to the same wifi the phone is on. So my recommendation is still to use the REST API. Sadly the use of WatchConnectivity places a lot of restrictions on the watch app (it can only get data from the phone when the phone app is running). Don't rely on what FB Messenger is doing, that's one of the worst watch apps. It wasn't working at all for months

Comment: @tymac so many people are using it, because there are certain tasks that can only be solved on the phone, so if you need to share data from those, you need to transfer it to the watch somehow. Moreover, a lot of companies still use legacy codebases and haven't updated their watchOS apps to do the networking in the watchOS extension (sadly watchOS is the last priority for most companies). I can't really answer the questions about the models or notifications without more context, so you're better off asking separate specific questions as you said.

Comment: You said `there are certain tasks that can only be solved on the phone...` For example? What would be these situations in a chat app that would require WC?

Comment: @DávidPásztor: Is there any support now for WatchOs 6 push notifications of firebase?

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala please check [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/269) link for specific Firebase features on watchOS

Answer (score 0):

Firebase v7.9.0 added WatchOS support for realtime database.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#realtime-database

Comment: ... and removed in 10.0.0. 
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#realtime-database 

And to be precise, watchOS 9 and above doesn't support Sockets, that's why REST API is the only guaranteed way to deal with Firebase RTDB on watchOS.