# Using Firebase with WatchOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, apple-watch

My issue is that I want to display some data pulled from a firebase node, on the Apple Watch.

Now, typically with the apple watch there would be 2 ways to get data from a remote source.

1 - You create a shared class, which makes the calls to the database and the watch calls the functions in this to get the data or..

2 - You make use of `NSURLSessions` and have the Watch talk to the backend and request the data itself.

Both options have some serious drawbacks. Drawbacks for option 1 are that if you need to import a framework, ie firebase to make your database calls, that will no longer work with the apple watch as the watch isn't firebase compatible at this time due to CFNetorking not getting ported to the new watchOS'. Issues with option 2 are that each device would need to maintain auth state, and while this feels like the less of 2 evils, still seems super hacky.

Does anyone else have any thoughts on any other ways we could do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using firebase with WatchKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472827/using-firebase-with-watchkit)

Comment: I've created a feature request to make it supported by Firebase SDK: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4556 please add a "thumbs up" emoji there (they rely on it to prioritize requests)