# Firebase Database on AppleWatch

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, watchos-5

I have a Firebase RealtimeDatabase to Display timetables on the iPhone. How can i get that data to AppleWatch? NSUserDelegate or WKUrlSession. I want to keep it as Updated as possible and I Made a Data Type for the TableCells. For NSUserDefaults I have to convert it. Cant i fetch the data From the Server Directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native support for WatchOS from the Firebase SDK. See this [feature request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/269) on the open-source github repo for that SDK.

Your best options at the moment are to either use the REST API directly from the watch, or to proxy all communications through the paired phone. See [Using firebase with WatchKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472827/using-firebase-with-watchkit)