# Apple WatchOs along with Firebase Cloud Messaging For Push Notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch, watchos-6

**Problem Statement:**

We have support for push notifications through Firebase Cloud Messaging Platform. It supports Android and IOS both but if we want the same on Apple WatchOS 6.0, does it work the same as IOS App on FCM or is it different?

**Related Questions Referred**:

I have gone through some related questions on Stackoverflow like       [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472827/using-firebase-with-watchkit) which answers for WatchOS 2 & 3 only but nothing for WatchOS 6.0.

I have also gone through the Firebase docs for support of WatchOS but found only related to IOS App, no mentions related to    WatchOS.

**Expected Solution:**

I want to implement push notifications for Apple WatchOS, hence which service should be used for the same. Should it be FCM or something else?

*Note: If anyone wants to know in which technology I will implement this, I will implement it using Ruby On Rails.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging introduced community support for watchOS in January 2020. More details in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios).

Comment: Hey, thanks! Just checked the link shared by you. Any idea if we need to do anything differently while setting up the FCM app setup or is it same as we do for IOS app?

Comment: See the sample at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/Example/watchOSSample